# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when using @synthesize

Tags: objective-c

.h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Tardies.h"
#import "DBAccess.h"

@interface TardiesViewController : UITableViewController
<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UIPrintInteractionControllerDelegate> {
    NSMutableArray *tardiesAry;
    UITableView *table;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *tardiesAry;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *table;

@end
```

.m file

```
#import "TardiesViewController.h"


@implementation TardiesViewController

@synthesize tardiesAry;
@synthesize table;

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    DBAccess *dbAccess = [[DBAccess alloc] init];
    self.tardiesAry = [dbAccess getTardies];
    [dbAccess closeDatabase];
    [dbAccess release];
    [table reloadData];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [super viewDidUnload];
    self.tardiesAry = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [tardiesAry release];
}

@end

- (NSMutableArray *) getTardies
{   
//  [self deleteFromTardies:@""];
NSLog (@"DBAccess - getTardies - 1");
NSMutableArray *tardies = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];

const char *sql = "SELECT tardies.studentId, tardyDate, tardyTime, lastName, firstName, middleName FROM tardies LEFT JOIN students ON tardies.studentId = students.studentId ORDER BY tardyDate desc, tardyTime desc, lastName, firstName, middleName";

sqlite3_stmt *statement;

int sqlResult = sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &statement, NULL);

if ( sqlResult == SQLITE_OK)
{
    NSLog (@"DBAccess - getTardies - 6");
    while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW )
    {
        Tardies *tardy = [[Tardies alloc] init];

        char *stuId = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0);
        char *trdyDate = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1);
        char *trdyTime = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2);
        char *lName = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 3);
        char *fName = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 4);
        char *mName = (char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 5);

        tardy.studentId = (stuId) ? [NSString stringWithUTF8String:stuId] : @" ";
        tardy.tardyDate = (trdyDate) ? [NSString stringWithUTF8String:trdyDate] : @" ";
        tardy.tardyTime = (trdyTime) ? [NSString stringWithUTF8String:trdyTime] : @" ";

        NSString *lNm = (lName) ? [NSString stringWithUTF8String:lName] : @" ";
        NSString *fNm = (fName) ? [NSString stringWithUTF8String:fName] : @" ";
        NSString *mNm = (mName) ? [NSString stringWithUTF8String:mName] : @" ";
        tardy.fullName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@ %@", lNm, fNm, mNm];

        NSDictionary *tardyDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:tardy.studentId, @"studentId", 
                                   tardy.tardyDate, @"tardyDate",
                                   tardy.tardyTime, @"tardyTime",
                                   tardy.fullName, @"fullName",
                                   nil];
        [tardies addObject:tardyDict];

        [tardy release];
        [tardyDict release];
    }
    //  Finalize the statement to release its resources
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);        
}
else 
{
    NSLog (@"Problem with the database:");
    NSLog (@"%d", sqlResult);
}
return tardies;
}

- (void) closeDatabase
{
    //  Close the database
    if (sqlite3_close(database) != SQLITE_OK) 
    {
    //  NSAssert1(0, @"Error: failed to close database: '%s' .", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    } 
}
```

Xcode Version 4.0 Build 4A304a

The first time the setTardiesAry runs, it is fine, the second time, the program fails on the @synthesize tardiesAry line with error:
Thread 1: Program received signal "EXC_BAD_ACCESS".

I tried overriding the method setTardiesAry, failed in that method instead of the @synthesize line instead.

Please help, I have no idea how to continue.

It was had an autorelease in getTardies.

Comment: Most likely the array returned by `[dbAccess getTardies]` contains objects that were released too many times. Please post the code for that method.

Comment: looks like something inside your DBAccess class is being over-released.

Comment: And @Anomie beat me to the punch

Comment: I would like to see the code for getTardies, and also closeDatabase

Comment: @Lacemaker: Note you can [format lines as code](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) by indenting them four spaces. The "{}" button in the editor toolbar does this for you. Edit your question and try it out to fix the formatting. Click the orange question mark in the editor toolbar for more information and tips on formatting.

Comment: ... [Sample code](http://sscce.org/) should be complete yet concise. While the first posted sample code was incomplete, it now contains extraneous code. As for how you could continue on your own, XCode has a decent interactive debugger; check the XCode documentation for the XCode Debugging Guide.

Comment: You answered your own question, post it as an answer below and mark it with a tick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

modify

here with ur dealloc

```
- (void)dealloc {

    [self.tardiesAry release];

}
```